# what's the meaning of cycles annotation in perf stat

Tags: linux, perf

```
      8.014196 task-clock                #    0.004 CPUs utilized          
           204 context-switches          #    0.025 M/sec                  
            32 cpu-migrations            #    0.004 M/sec                  
             0 page-faults               #    0.000 K/sec                  
    11,841,196 cycles                    #    1.478 GHz                     [46.17%]
     9,982,788 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   84.31% frontend cycles idle    [80.26%]
     8,122,708 stalled-cycles-backend    #   68.60% backend  cycles idle   
     5,462,302 instructions              #    0.46  insns per cycle        
                                         #    1.83  stalled cycles per insn
     1,098,309 branches                  #  137.045 M/sec                  
        94,430 branch-misses             #    8.60% of all branches         [77.23%]
```

what's the meaning of **1.478 GHz** and **[46.17%]** in cycles's annotation.

Comment: hulk, can you rerun the program with smaller set of hw events to disable multiplexing? `perf stat -e task-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,branches  ./your_test_program`

Comment: @osgx `
         62.152716 task-clock                #    0.003 CPUs utilized           [100.00%]
             2,182 context-switches          #    0.035 M/sec                   [100.00%]
                 5 cpu-migrations            #    0.080 K/sec                   [100.00%]
                 2 page-faults               #    0.032 K/sec                  
       110,938,674 cycles                    #    1.785 GHz                    
        52,245,072 instructions              #    0.47  insns per cycle        
        10,107,248 branches                  #  162.620 M/sec                  

`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a thing I hate very much on `perf`, that the documentation and manual pages are outdated and searching for meaning of some values is pretty complicated. I did search for them once so I add my findings:

> what's the meaning of **1.478 GHz**

To my knowledge, the value after `#` is recalculation of the native counter value (the value in the first column) to the user-readable form. This value should roughly correspond to clock speed of your processor:

```
grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo
```

should give similar value. It is printed from [tools/perf/util/stat-shadow.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/util/stat-shadow.c#L407).

> and **[46.17%]** in cycles's annotation?

This value should correspond the the portion of time, the hardware counter was active. Perf allows to start more hardware counters and multiplex them in runtime, which makes it easier for programmer.

I didn't found the actual place in the code, but it is described in one recently [proposed patch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/3/1/562) as (part of `csv` format):

```
+   - percentage of measurement time the counter was running
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @Jakuje. And 1.478 GHz seems caculate from (cycles * 1000)/task-clock.  On the other hand,  ”This value should roughly correspond to clock speed of your processor“ , the value cat /proc/cpuinfo is 2.2GHz, but value in perf stat out is only 1.2G, when cpu usage about 90%.

Comment: hulk, the frequency of CPU may change. Sometimes it will also be changed in /proc/cpuinfo, but `perf stat -e cycles,task-clock ./program` is more accurate, if there is `[100%]` annotation in line with cycles.

Comment: @osgx ala Intel Turbo magic or similar in other processors. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @hulk: Only long-running processes that keep the CPU pegged at max frequency should expect the calculated frequency to match their rated (or max turbo) frequency.  Things like `perf stat --all-user` can throw that off, too.  See also [Understanding the Frequency printed by Linux Perf Stat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68659506)

Comment: I am wondering about the difference between ```task-time``` and ```user time```. I did not find any good explanation on this two timing value.